# how to declare templated map::iterator within a templated class. following code Says ; expected when compiled

Tags: c++, templates, stl, dictionary, compiler-errors

the following code says 
 error: expected ‘;’ before ‘forwit’ 
 error: expected ‘;’ before ‘revit’

```
template<class T>
class mapping {

public:
    map<T,int> forw;
    map<int,T> rev;
    int curr;
    //typeof(forw)::iterator temp;
    map<T,int>::iterator forwit;
    map<int,T>::iterator revit;
};

//    }; // JVC: This was present, but unmatched.
```

i have completely no idea what the problem is? please help.

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please post some real code?  That won't compile as there is nothing between `template` and `class mapping`.  Furthermore, to help you we need to know to what `map` refers.  Is is a typedef? a user-defined class?

Comment: mukul, why did you edit the code formatting to a worse version?

Comment: Earlier i used just <code> tag to format my code and found that only one line was displayed formatted. Then i read help and found the general convention of putting <pre><code> block and it also worked well (displayed the whole block of code formatted). Hence i edited the code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To help the compiler understand you are talking about a type in a templated context, you have to help it writing `typename`.

In your case

```
typename map<T,int>::iterator forwit;
```

Comment: @mukul: If this answer solved your problem(s) (and it seems it did), you should **accept it**. This is how StackOverflow works.

Comment: I was waiting for the timer to complete. It was saying something like 7 more mins to accept an answer.

Comment: Just a simple question. If all the answers satisfy you equally and solved my problem, then how to accept the one. Should i accept the earliest replied or what. is there some way of paying back gratitude to show yes this user provides very precise answers.

Comment: To reward all answers, just vote for it.
The accepted answer is for people looking for the same answer. You should take the most precise one (for example with interesting comments).

Comment: Why is that? Actually I don't get it why it is not necessary to put that "typename" when you are on Visual C++. Furthermore what is the logic reason to put that when you are using templated clsses? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Add `typename`:

```
typename map<T,int>::iterator forwit;
typename map<int,T>::iterator revit;
```

Since `map<T,int>` depends on the template parameter, it isn't known until the template is instantiated whether `iterator` is a type or a static member; unless you use `typename` to specify that it is a type, the compiler will assume the latter.

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell the compiler `map<T,int>::iterator` is a type by the `typename` keyword.

```
typename map<T,int>::iterator forwit;
```